# jCarousel, IE6 and Fixed Width

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, jcarousel

We are using jCarousel on our websites to display images. Simple enough. We have fairly flexible layouts so the carousels are not always the same width.

FF, IE7+, Chrome, Safari etc work perfectly well taking up the space available. However IE6 ends up sending the jCarousel script into a loop and warns that a script is stopping the page from loading correctly.

To stop IE6 from failing we are having to specify a fixed width in CSS for the carousel container. Is this a problem that others have had with IE6 and jCarousel?

Comment: If we stop making things compatible with IE6 maybe people will actually stop using it

Comment: I tell management that every day but they pay the bill not me. Current client has a large user base in China where the majority of the world's IE6 users are

Answer (score 1):

I used this to fix that problem:

```
/*fixes jcarousel jquery error*/
    .panel-pane .content {
    display: block !important;
  }
```

Comment: What is the ".panel-pane .content" element?